# Let $f$ be a polynomial function on the entire complex plane such that $() ≠ 0$ for $z$ such that $|z|< 1$ ; then which of the following is true?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Let $~f~$ be a polynomial function on the entire complex plane such that $~() ≠ 0~$ for $~z~$ such that $~|z|< 1~$ ; then  $$\dfrac {1}{2}~∫_{|z|=1} \dfrac{f'()}{()} $$
$1. ~~$can take any integer values
$2. ~~$can take any value
$3. ~~$is zero
$4. ~~$is equal to degree of $f$.

**My thoughts:** Argument theorem says, if $f(z)$ be analytic inside and on a simple closed curve C except for a finite number of poles inside C. Suppose that $f(z)\ne0$ on C. If N and P are, respectively the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside C, counting multiplicities, then $$\dfrac {1}{2}~\oint_C \dfrac{f'()}{()} =N-P~.$$
We know that every polynomial of degree $n$ has  exactly $n$ zeros and has no pole. Therefore in this case $~N=n~($degree of the polynomial function$)~,~P=0~.$ Therefore  $$\dfrac {1}{2}~∫_{|z|=1} \dfrac{f'()}{()} =\text{degree of the polynomial function}~f$$ So here option $4$ is true but answer given here is option $3$. Please help.

Comment: You have to count not all the zeros and poles, but the zeros and poles inside the circle.

Comment: consider $f(z) = (z-1)^k$ or $f(z) = z^k -1$

Answer (score 2):

It is $0$ because, by the Argument Principle, that integral is equal to the number of zeros minus the number of poles (counted with their multiplicities) *in the open unit disk*.

Comment: The argument principle also requires that $f(z) \ne 0$ on the contour. Unless I am mistaken, the integral is not defined otherwise.

Comment: @MartinR If $f(z)=0$ for some $z\in S^1$, then the integral $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,\mathrm dz$ itself doesn't make sense. So, it seems to me that it is implicitly assumed here that $|z|=1\implies f(z)\ne0$ too.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos :  So it means that outside the open unit disk $(~|z|\ge 1~),$ the value of the integral is zero everywhere. Is it ?

Comment: Not at all. Where did you read that in my answer? If, say, $f(z)=z−2$, then the integral is equal to $0$, but if you compute the integral along the circle $|z|=3$, then it will be equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

One direct prof. We can assume that the leading coefficient is $1$. Since $f(z)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$ on the entire complex plan, $f(z)= \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(z-z_k \right)$ where $z_k, k = \overline{1,n}$. Then:
$$ f'(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{j\neq k}(z-z_j) \Rightarrow \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{z-z_k}, z \neq z_k$$
Now, combine with the fact that none of $z_i \notin \overline{B}(0,1)$ by Cauchy's integral theorem:
$$\dfrac {1}{2}~\oint_C \dfrac{f'()}{()} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \oint_{\vert z \vert = 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-z_k} = 0$$

Comment: I think it should be $~z_i \notin \overline{B}(-1,1)~$. Is not it ?  @NguyễnQuân

Comment: $\overline{B}(0,1) = \{z: \vert z \vert \leq 1\}$ so $z_i \notin \overline{B}(0,1)$ is equivalent to $f(z) \neq 0$ for $z$ such that $\vert z \vert \leq 1$. We must have $\leq$ cause the integral will be meaningless when there is a discontinuous point on the curve $\vert z \vert = 1$